# Draw a Grid layout based on known cols and rows

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to draw a gridlayout based on a given number of known squares.
Example, 16 squares, makes 8x8 grid.
But my grid looks a little bit odd, can't help it :(

[image]

**edit: added wrong picture in first place!**

```
        int n = 16;
        int grid = (int)Math.Sqrt(n);
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int yCounter = 0;
        int xCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            myGeometricObject[i] = new GeometricObject();

            x = xCounter * 50;
            xCounter++;


            if(i % grid == 0 && i > 0)
            {
                yCounter++;
                xCounter = 0;
                y = yCounter * 50;
            }

            myGeometricObject[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            myGeometricObject[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            this.Controls.Add(myGeometricObject[i]);
        }
```

Comment: `Example, 16 squares, makes 8x8 grid.` - err.... what??? 8*8 == 64, not 16...

Comment: Also, use WPF, and this becomes a single line: `<UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="8"/>`. Forget useless winforms which forces you to reinvent the wheel for everything.

Comment: sry changed my exmaple due to testings, in this case its 4, sry

Comment: a) are you sure you got the right image uploaded now? b) what is odd: the 8th square or the slimmer right and bottom sides?

Comment: Its the correct picture due to the given code.
Second line 4th square moves out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 lines have to be moved, like this:

```
    int n = 16;
    int grid = (int)Math.Sqrt(n);
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int yCounter = 0;
    int xCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        myGeometricObject[i] = new GeometricObject();

        if(i % grid == 0 && i > 0)
        {
            yCounter++;
            xCounter = 0;
            y = yCounter * 50;
        }
        // Next 2 lines
        x = xCounter * 50;
        xCounter++;

        myGeometricObject[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        myGeometricObject[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
        this.Controls.Add(myGeometricObject[i]);
    }
```

Oh, see that you've solved it youself. Always good!

Answer (score 1):

Solved, correct Code stated as following

```
        int n = 16;
        int grid = (int)Math.Sqrt(n);
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int yCounter = 0;
        int xCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            myGeometricObject[i] = new GeometricObject();

            if (i % grid == 0)
            {
                y = yCounter * 50;
                yCounter++;
                xCounter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                xCounter++;
            }

            x = xCounter * 50;

            myGeometricObject[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            myGeometricObject[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            this.Controls.Add(myGeometricObject[i]);
        }
```